# Is my restore purchases code correct and if so where should I put the action to change user defaults?

Tags: swift, in-app-purchase, restore, storekit

I am writing my first iOS app in Swift and have been having some problems with the in-app purchases functionality. I think I've got the actual buy function working but I'm not sure about the restore functionality. I'm just providing one product which is a 'pro' version of the app. This is stored in the User Defaults location and having it unlocks the extra functionality. My restore function is confusing me, can someone have a look at it and tell me where I should be setting my User Defaults value? Should it be within the paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished function or the paymentQueue function?

```
import UIKit
import StoreKit

class StoreController: UIViewController, SKProductsRequestDelegate, 
SKPaymentTransactionObserver   {

// Properties
var defaults = UserDefaults.standard
var list = [SKProduct]()
var p = SKProduct()

// Methods
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Get list of products for the store
    localTitle.isEnabled = false
    localDescription.isEnabled = false
    price.isEnabled = false
    buy.isEnabled = false
    restore.isEnabled = false
    getProducts()
}

// Outlets
@IBOutlet weak var localTitle: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var localDescription: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var price: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var buy: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var restore: UIButton!

// Actions
@IBAction func buy(_ sender: UIButton) {
    print("buy pressed")
    for product in list {
        let prodID = product.productIdentifier
        if(prodID == "com.squidgylabs.pro") {
            p = product
            buyProduct()
        }
    }
}

@IBAction func restore(_ sender: UIButton) {
    print("restore pressed")
    SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)
    SKPaymentQueue.default().restoreCompletedTransactions()
}

// Methods
func getProducts() {
    print("starting  getproducts function")
    if(SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments()) {
        print("IAP is enabled, loading")
        let productID: NSSet = NSSet(objects: "com.squidgylabs.pro")
        let request: SKProductsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productID as! Set<String>)
        request.delegate = self
        request.start()
    } else {
        print("please enable IAPS")
    }
}


func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {
    print("starting productsrequest")
    let myProduct = response.products
    for product in myProduct {
        print("product added")
        list.append(product)
    }
    localTitle.isEnabled = true
    localDescription.isEnabled = true
    restore.isEnabled = true
    buy.isEnabled = true
    price.isEnabled = true

    // Update labels
    localTitle.text = list[0].localizedTitle
    localDescription.text = list[0].localizedDescription
    // Format the price and display
    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.locale = Locale.current
    formatter.numberStyle = .currency
    if let formattedPrice = formatter.string(from: list[0].price){
        price.text = formattedPrice
    }
}


func paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue) {
    print("starting paymentQueueResoreCompletedTransactionsFnished")
    for transaction in queue.transactions {
        let t: SKPaymentTransaction = transaction
        let prodID = t.payment.productIdentifier as String

        switch prodID {
        case "com.squidgylabs.pro":
            print("case is correct product ID in payment...finished")

        default:
            print("IAP not found")
        }
    }
}

func buyProduct() {
    print("buy " + p.productIdentifier)
    let pay = SKPayment(product: p)
    SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)
    SKPaymentQueue.default().add(pay as SKPayment)
}

func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
    print("entering func paymentQueue")

    for transaction: AnyObject in transactions {
        let trans = transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction

        switch trans.transactionState {
        case .purchased:
            print("buy ok, unlock IAP HERE")

            print(p.productIdentifier)
            let prodID = p.productIdentifier
            switch prodID {
            case "com.squidgylabs.pro":
                print("setting pro in defaults...")
                defaults.set(true, forKey: "pro")
            default:
                print("IAP not found")
            }
            queue.finishTransaction(trans)
            break
        case .failed:
            print("buy error")
            queue.finishTransaction(trans)
            break
        case .restored:
            print("case .restored in paymentQ")
            SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction)
            queue.finishTransaction(trans)
            break
        default:
            print("Default")
            break
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I don't know that it matters. Your code is pretty much the same as mine. I (re)set the UserDefaults in`paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue)`. I do however perform `finishTransaction` in `paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction])`. **Again, I'm not sure it matters. Hopefully somebody will correct me if it does!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be done like this.

```
public func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
    for transaction in transactions {
        switch transaction.transactionState {
        case .purchased:
            completePurchaseForTransaction(transaction)
        case .restored:
            completePurchaseForTransaction(transaction)
        default:
            break
    }
}

private func completePurchaseForTransaction(_ transaction: SKPaymentTransaction) {
    let productIdentifier = transaction.payment.productIdentifier
    // Update UserDefaults here
    SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
}
```

You might consider using other class for StoreKit access instead of a UIViewController. Because

> Your application should always expect to be notified of completed
>   transactions.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skpaymentqueue/1506042-add

And View controllers come and go. It might even crash the app if you don't remove object you added as an observer to the SKPaymentQueue.

I have simple, well-documented StoreKit library on GitHub that you might check out to get the idea -- https://github.com/suvov/VSStoreKit

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I agree that it is better practice to have the store kit functionality in its own class. The problem I was having with that was how to reference back to the view controller. E.g. How to tell the view controller: hey we have the price now for your buy button to display. Because I don't know what the object name for the UIViewcontroller is at runtime.  How should I do this? I sort of need the view controller to listen for changes in the store kit object then update itself accordingly.

Comment: You can use delegate https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html or NSNotification https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsnotification to "talk" to your ViewController from object that manages purchases. Or a callback function https://medium.cobeisfresh.com/why-you-shouldn-t-use-delegates-in-swift-7ef808a7f16b